# VueJS - How to track change event of a content from component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-timeago

I have a `VueJS` application using `vue-timeago` for showing the elapsed time in some divs.

This is the `HTML` code where timeago is:

```
<div>
        <timeago
          :since="item.timestamp"
          :auto-update="60">
        </timeago>
      </div>
```

[image]

I want to be able to trigger an event when elapsed time is greater than 50 minutes.

From reading https://github.com/egoist/vue-timeago API, they dont have such functionality implemented. So maybe a workaround is to look into the output value into the DOM and see when it changes and then do the comparing logic.

> Is there a way I can `watch` when that `InnerHTML` value changes and then compare the string?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use something like the moment.js library to do calculations directly with **item.timestamp** as this feels a bit hacky.

In answer to your question - The innerText is not reactive but you can set it to a value that is and watch that variable.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <timeago
      :since="item.timestamp"
      :auto-update="60"
      ref="myTimeStamp">
    </timeago>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      timeago: null
    }
  },
  watch: {
    timeago: function() {
      console.log("WATCH:", this.timeago)
    }
  },
  created() {
    let self = this;
    setInterval(() => {
        this.timeago = self.$refs['myTimeStamp'].$el.innerText;
    }, 1000);
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I have a parent that has a v-for that renders the above code, so I can have multiple instances of that template. I guess would be better to do your logic in parent view right? So we just have 1 setInterval. I’m I correct?

Comment: My example answers your question of how to access and watch the innerHtml (innerText is probably more appropriate). An element inside a v-for with a **ref** attribute will result in an array inside the $refs['myTimeStamp']. I started to code it but it is beyond ugly. I had a look around and found the javascript-time-ago package. I would create a method that accepts the item.timestamp and returns the timeago using the above library. You trigger any code inside this method.

Comment: Im going to test it and le tyou know. Thanks